# VBA freaking out when I try to use a max function?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two spreadsheets, one is a column for names and then a bunch of columns for time slots. If a person is scheduled for that timeslot, they have a 1 in that column. I also have a schedule sheet which has days across the top and times across the side and needs to be populated with a list of names. I'm trying to write a macro to autopopulate it. It's working great when all the timeslots for a particular day/time are full. Say Monday at 6-8am and Monday 8-10am both have 6 slots, I run my macro and they fill up perfectly. But if Monday 6-8am has 5 people signed up instead of 6, the first person for 8-10am will end up in the last slot for 6-8. Here is the code:

```
Sub copytoschedule()


Dim i As Integer

Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(" rawweekdayw")

Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weekdays W")

'For Mon 6-8am

For i = 3 To ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

Dim rowcount As Integer

rowcount = ws2.Cells(40, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    If ws1.Cells(i, 4) = 1 Then ws2.Cells(rowcount, 2).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 2).Value

Next i


'For Mon 8-10am

For i = 3 To ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

Dim rowcount2 As Integer

rowcount2 = ws2.Cells(40, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    If ws1.Cells(i, 5) = 1 Then ws2.Cells(rowcount2, 2).Value = ws1.Cells(i, 2).Value

Next i
```

I tried to fix this by replacing the rowcount variable for the second time slot with this:

```
rowcount2 = max((ws2.Cells(40, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1),8)
```

because the rows for that time slot start in row 8. When I try to run it, VBA says it's out of memory and excel crashes. Help?!?

Comment: Never mind, got around it by using if /else to achieve same thing as a max function!

Comment: You can't use Max by itself in VBA: needs to be `Application.Max` (you are essentially using the worksheet function, not a "native" VBA Max)

Comment: You should use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Max` (rather than just `Application.Max`, which is Excel 95 syntax) in order to get strong-types and intellisense and syntax checking.